# how to provide-inject an object of a class

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vue-composition-api

as shown in the below posted code, i am creating the class `GISWSCaller.ts`. i want to be able to use `provide/inject` api to let this class `GISWSCaller.ts` provids `GISWSContext` as follows:

```
provide("GISWSContext",ctx)
```

the problem i am facing now, is that the line `provide("GISWSContext",ctx)` is causing an error as it is not identified by vs-codes, as shown in the screen-shot attached.

please let me know why i am getting this error and how to fix it.

**GISWSCaller.ts**:

```
import { defineEmits, provide,computed } from 'vue';
private const res = undefined
private let params = undefined

class GISWSCaller{
  private emit = defineEmits({
  evtRunWSRouteTest:async (params) => {
    const splitted = params.split(',')
    if (splitted.length == 4) {
      const response = await fetch('https://xx/xx/getDistanceFromOriginToDestination/' + params)
      res.value =  await response.json()
      return res.value
    }
    return false
  }
})

private writableCompPropsEvtEmitterParams = computed({
  get() {
    return params
  },
  set(newValue) {
    this.emit('evtRunWSRouteTest',newValue)
  }
})

// functions
public unregisterEvtEmitter() {
  this.writableCompPropsEvtEmitterParams.value = undefined
}

ctx = {
  "writableCompPropsEvtEmitterParams":this.writableCompPropsEvtEmitterParams,
  "unregisterEvtEmitter":this.unregisterEvtEmitter
}

provide("GISWSContext",ctx)

}
```

**img**:

[image]

Comment: You can't write a class like that, for starters. defineEmits is allowed only in `script setup`. provide is allowed only in comp setup.  And you want to avoid using classes in Vue for numerous reasons. The screenshot is unreadable, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors . If there's an error, please, list it. Your solution went wrong at some point, consider addressing a correct way to solve it rather than posting several questions regarding the implementation, which is incorrect. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks..however, do you think i should use `export function xx` instead of a class?! it is allowed in vue please?

Comment: It's most likely the case, most things you can do with classes you can do with functional programming without losing functionality and comfort, it's all about the syntax. Vue favors the latter. If this piece of code is supposed to be reusable in comps, it likely needs to be a composable function, that's what they are for

Comment: @EstusFlask so do you recommend not using neither export functions nor class please?

Comment: Depends on your case. In case of a composable it would be export function. See https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html

Comment: @EstusFlask morning, i have a question please, when i was using angular, and i wanted to create a button,input,tabs or any gui-element, i used to refer to `https://clarity.design/documentation/get-started` now i am working with vue, and i do not know what is the official website for gui-elements for vue? can you please tell me what is it`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Clarity is a third-party ui lib, and it's available for Ng only. Pick the one that works with Vue if you don't want to write it from scratch. Primevue is ok

Comment: @EstusFlask i mean what if i want to create vue component with tabs as the one shown in this link:https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tabs            where should i go or google?should i just refer to clarity?

Comment: Still not sure. Do you want to write custom vue ui comps that conform clarity design system? Then likely yes, you can refer its documentation. Otherwise pick an existing third-party ui lib that fits you best and refer their official docs

Comment: @EstusFlask i do not do any thing related to clarity. would you please tell me an example of third-part ui for vue?